# Does any other language have as many reflexive pronouns as English?

Tags: pronouns, reflexive

1st person: myself, ourselves

2nd person: yourself yourselves

3rd person: himself, herself, itself, themselves, oneself

In Latin, French, Spanish, Italian, and German there is only one reflexive pronoun, used only in the third person, except that in those last four it's also a second person "polite" as opposed to "familiar" second-person pronoun. In Swahili there's a single reflexive infix.

Comment: I don't see why this is a question about English. You are explicitly asking about other languages. Perhaps it would be better asked on [linguistics.se]?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not asking about English but about how other languages compare to English.

Comment: Of course it is about English. Just rephrase it, if you want: *Does English really have more reflexive pronouns than any other language?"

Comment: And why are not *me* and *te* reflexive pronouns in French? Same for *nous* and *vous*. They're not ***only*** reflexive pronouns the way *se* is, but when you put a third-person sentence with a reflexive pronoun into first person, *se* changes to *me*.

Comment: See for example [this conjugation](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french-verb-se%20laver.html) of *se laver*.

Comment: Whether English has more reflexive pronouns than other languages is about English. One cannot entirely exclude comparisons and contrasts between English and other languages from discussion of English.

Comment: @PeterShor : I think you answered your own question. There is no need for such a concept as that of a "reflexive pronoun" until there is a pronoun that is used only reflexively. (And likewise in German, "mich" and "dich" and "uns" and "euch" are not used _only_ reflexively.)

Comment: There's also 'themself'.

Comment: If this is allowed because it partly concerns the English language, translation requests become equally valid. It's about comparative linguistics, and here, the comparison seems not germane. English has (arguably, now that 'themself' is arguably considered acceptable) all the reflexive pronouns it needs, and not too many.

Comment: @Edwin: singular *ourself* is missing from the list. (*Each of us needs to decide for ourself*.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy: if the objective and nominative pronouns have the same form for ***all*** pronouns, for example, then there's no need for such a concept as an objective pronoun. But in English, we certainly have an objective second person pronoun (*you*). The fact that it's the same form as the nominative second person pronoun is immaterial. Would you say that *me* is objective in *she loves me* but *you* is not objective in *she loves you*? Would you say that *il se lave* is reflexive, but *je me lave* is not?

Comment: @PeterShor : Isn't there a difference between saying the whole sentence or clause is reflexive, or that that way of using the verb in combination with that pronoun is reflexive, and saying the pronoun itself is a reflexive pronoun?

Comment: Swahili has one reflexive verbal prefix, but multiple reflexive words analogous to "our-selves" (*mwenyewe, chenyewe*). Related Logoori is a candidate for "most", with 19 noun classes.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on whether or not you consider the morphology to produce other words.

From functional standpoint, all words in your example contain **a single morpheme `-self-`** which introduces reflexive meaning.

Otherwise, if *myself* and *yourself* are considered **essentially different** then you take a language with 4, 6, 7, or 25 noun cases, take a single reflexive pronoun *myself* and get a result of 25 essentially different words.

And 25 more for *yourself*, 25 for *himself* and for each word listed in the question.

All these produced words would be reflexive pronouns.

Comment: Do you mean noun classes, or noun cases? E.g. "Myself(nom); myself(acc); myself(loc.)" and if the latter, what's an example?

Comment: @user6726, I meant the noun cases. The OQ claims that the are "many" reflexive pronouns, but all their examples are results of morphology effects (e.g. agglutination) involving a single morpheme. The noun cases also produce results like "myself/GEN" or "myself/ACC", which can be treated different words, according the OP's logic.

Comment: A good example of this seems to be ancient Greek [(Link)](http://www.chlt.org/FirstGreekBook/JWW_FGB48.html), which I don't know at all. But the linked page lists something like 24 reflexive pronouns, taking all the genders and cases into account.

Comment: The reflexive pronouns in English are not just the products of a purely transparent process that takes another pronoun and adds "self". The "self" part is consistent, but the other part can be identical to either the accusative ("himself, themselves") or the genitive ("myself", "yourself", "ourselves"). We could say that  "the genitive is used for non-third-person pronouns, and the accusative for third-person pronouns" but it seems doubtful to me that present-day English speakers internalize this as a process rather than just memorizing the forms.

Comment: (Historically, "himself" comes from 'him" + the adjective "self", while "yourself" and "ourself" seem to come from possessives + a noun "self". So the original structure of their formation appears to be different.)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, French has more than one reflexive pronoun.

Clitic reflexive pronouns:

me, te, se, nous, vous

Comment: *moi-même* etc. aren't actually reflexive, but intensive.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll edit for clarity.